# How to get main div html to print a list of posts inside?

Tags: custom-post-types, themes, query-posts

I have created a function that lists custom post types with a specific term and prints the html. I'm using it as part of my plugin code.
I reused part of this information: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-wordpress-custom-post-types-creation-display-and-meta-boxes--wp-27645 (step 3)

This is fine, but the html structure that is harcoded on the code I built:

```
<div id="main-content" class="main-content">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
      <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
         <!-- articles iteration -->
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Won't be the same one of the theme installed on the site the plugin will live in.
Is there a way to obtain that html wrapper programatically?

Thanks

Comment: What's the scope of the function you built? Is it designed to be a template tag? Or is it attached to a hook to display in `the_content`?

Comment: It's attached to a hook, depending of the parameters I read from the url I display a list of posts.

Comment: I'd attempt to add minimal markup and follow Wordpress standards where possible. If your plugin creates a CPT and displays it on the frontend via a template you made, make sure you provide the user with the ability to overwrite the template by creating a template of the same name in their theme. That way, you can provide the user with basic styling via your plugin, with the option to expand/overwrite. I'm not a plugin designer per se, but this is my take.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look to themes code I realized that all those html parts I wanted where hardcoded on the themes files, so there wasn't any nice way to retrieve those chunks of html

I followed Strap1 comment and enabled my plugin to override my template, otherwise I parse the file page.php from the theme, to extract the html I need, using the function token_get_all().